# Make the windows cursor bigger on windows 8

Tags: c++, windows-8.1

I'd like to make the windows cursor bigger. I have a c++ windows application with the following code that I hijacked from a similar question. I am loading a cursor from a .cur file.

Already tried this link: [The biggest size of Windows Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100636/the-biggest-size-of-windows-cursor)
can't decide if the answer is "impossible" or "possible".

I've tried this and it **doesn't** work on windows 8 --> i'm loading a 128x128 file and it still appears very small (32x32). can anyone post something that has actually worked for them?

```
// load cursor resource into hCursor
HCURSOR ghTouchCursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(NULL, L"NormalHand.cur", IMAGE_CURSOR, 0,0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
// must copy cursor, windows is a pita...
HCURSOR ghCopyTouchCursor = CopyCursor(ghTouchCursor);
// set the cursor as the new full-screen cursor
SetSystemCursor(ghCopyTouchCursor, 32512);
```

i've also tried calling the load image like this, no difference.

```
HCURSOR ghTouchCursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(NULL, L"NormalHand.cur", IMAGE_CURSOR, 128,128, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXCURSOR) returns 32 but according to the official site:
"SetSystemCursor... You can use this function to set a cursor of any size."

It seems like there is consensus around "impossible".

Comment: What is the output of `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXCURSOR)`? This is the width of the cursor the system can use. From msdn *"The width of a cursor, in pixels. The system cannot create cursors of other sizes."*.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp answered in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The max cursor size depends on the system

The size in pixels of a cursor supported by the system can be retrieved by calling [`GetSystemMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), invoked with `SM_CXCURSOR` for the *width*, and `SM_CYCURSOR` for the *height*.

As stated by *msdn* this is the **only** size the system can use when creating cursors, which means that if you are using a bigger size in your call to [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that will be ignored.

---

#### Any alternative solutions?

If you want a bigger cursor, but the system prevents you from creating one, an alternative would be to hide the current cursor, and have an image float around where the cursor actually is.

This way the user will think that the cursor has changed, but in reality the cursor is invisible, and a image has been set in its place.

Comment: @sehe Sarcasm: disabled. This is an excellent idea that introduces a whole new set of problems that I've been trying to avoid. If anyone is curious what those problems are, I humbly offer a link. I've approved this answer so we can all agree that cursors larger than 32 are in fact impossible, unless anyone has any new information that isn't included already in the post.      stackoverflow.com/questions/23719372/… and also stackoverflow.com/questions/1343112/… –

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is for Windows 8, but this question still shows up in 2021, and having a large cursor is very much possible in Windows 10.

The latest documentation for the width and height parameters for LoadImage ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea)) states:

> The width, in pixels, of the icon or cursor. If this parameter is zero and the fuLoad parameter is LR_DEFAULTSIZE, the function uses the SM_CXICON or SM_CXCURSOR system metric value to set the width. If this parameter is zero and LR_DEFAULTSIZE is not used, the function uses the actual resource width.

So if you pass in 0 for width and height and ***do not*** pass in `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` it will use the size of the resource. So if your cursor has a 64x64 image in it, it will display at that size even if the system pointer is 32x32.

Example:

```
HCURSOR custom_cursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR1), IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, 0);
SetCursor(custom_cursor);
```

As a bonus, this also respects the Ease of Access settings in windows so the cursor will increase in size if the user has set the default cursor to be larger.