# How to set a cursor of non-standard size in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, autohotkey

I am attempting to change the cursor in Windows 10 (version 1703) to a custom made one (conditional on some event when a script activates), that is larger than the default 32 by 32 size. The MWE based on my Autohotkey script is the following:

```
ImagePath = %A_ScriptDir%\foo.cur
Cursor_ID := 32512   ; Standard arrow
Cursor_Size := 128

^0::
    SetSystemCursor( ImagePath, Cursor_ID, Cursor_Size, Cursor_Size )
return

SetSystemCursor( path, id, sizeX, sizeY )
{
    Cursor := DllCall( "LoadImage",
        UInt,0, Str,path, UInt,0x2, Int,sizeX, Int,sizeY, UInt,0x00000010, Ptr)
    DllCall( "SetSystemCursor", Ptr,Cursor, Int,id )
}
```

(My code is based off of that found at https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/32608-changing-the-system-cursor/.)

As far as I can tell from the [documentation of LoadImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(v=VS.85).aspx), the function `SetSystemCursor(...)` should load the image with dimensions `(sizeX, sizeY)` when those parameters are not 0 (since the flag `LR_DEFAULTSIZE = 0x00000040` is not set), but instead I get the following behaviour: no matter what sizes I set, the image gets scaled to `(sizeX, sizeY)`, and *then* down/upscaled to (32, 32). This is most obvious by setting, say `Cursor_Size := 2`, then I get an upscaled version of a 2 by 2 image.

After some searching around I have found both information suggesting that this *should* work, and also to the effect that the size of cursors is *always* dictated by `getSystemMetrics(SM_CXCURSOR)`
and `getSystemMetrics(SM_CYCURSOR)`: [The biggest size of Windows Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100636/the-biggest-size-of-windows-cursor) (see also [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Additional tests/ideas I've tried:

1. I checked the dimensions of the image corresponding to the handle returned
   by `LoadImage`, and it seems to be `(sizeX, sizeY)`, just as it should be, 
   therefore the scaling to 32 most likely happens upon executing `SetSystemCursor`.
2. I wanted to see if an application-specific cursor could bypass the
   apparent 32 by 32 restriction, so using Resource Hacker, I replaced one of 
   the resources in Paint. It was scaled down to size 32 in the same way.
3. Setting the values that are returned by
   `getSystemMetrics(SM_CXCURSOR)` and `getSystemMetrics(SM_CYCURSOR)`
   might be an option if these indeed restrict cursor sizes, but I
   could not find an appropriate function. I checked
   [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx), but the only remotely relevant option
   I found was `SPI_SETCURSORS`, and that just reloads the cursors from
   registry.

   It might be possible to change a registry value, though it would not
   be my preferred solution, as it would most likely require a reboot
   to take effect. Additionally, I haven't been able to find the relevant key.

My question would therefore be the following:

Is there a way to add an image of arbitrary size as a cursor in Windows 10, preferably without the need to reboot the computer? If so, how? Do `SM_CXCURSOR` and `SM_CYCURSOR` absolutely restrict the cursor's size? If they do, can these values be changed somehow?

EDIT:

It has been pointed out that yes, [the documentation of GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) states "the system cannot create cursors of other sizes" than `SM_CXCURSOR` and `SM_CYCURSOR`, but at the same time at some of the other webpages I linked, people seem to claim to be able to create arbitrary sized cursors. Hence my request for confirmation/clarification of the matter.

Apart from that, the question about changing these values, or the existence of any other possible workaround would still be important to me.

Comment: This would contradict lots of other information I found though, although those may or may not be up to date and relevant. And even if that is true, my other question stands, about whether it is possible to change those values.

Comment: There used to be some silly tools that made the global cursors giant in size and animated but they might have faked it with a mouse hook and a always on top window.

Comment: @Anders Can you recall what these tools are? It may or may not help in my case, but I'd like to at least check them out.